# How do I tie up an inheritance?

Tags: united-states, investment-strategies, inheritance, family

I stand to inherit a large estate over the next ten years or so. The inheritance will come from my direct parents and step parents, who have no other children.

However, I know that other members of my family will pressure me to share money and property that they have no legal right to. I have my own career and live comfortably enough that I don't need the money. But I don't want people to take what my parents didn't want them to have.

How can I tie up an investment portfolio, bank account, and property (if possible) such that even I don't have access to it for a few years?

Comment: How is its location/status any of their business? Just tell them it's tied up. The details aren't their concern. The real issue is that you should invest it in the way that be best for you. I don't know what you consider "large," but a thought - having 25 times one's current income is putting them in the range of 'able to retire' or at least 'set for life'. Assuming the current income has you happy.

Answer (score 2):

Well you have three main options in my opinion.

#### Bonds/Fixed Term Deposits

For cash, or any assets you can convert to cash, you could purchase bonds with a maturity date close to what you are looking to lock your funds up for. While you could sell these on a secondary market, admittedly - however you have a justification you can provide to yourself as to why you cannot sell them.

Fixed term deposits often have poor interest rates, but if you ask to withdraw your money early you often forfeit all of the interest you would have gained.

#### Equity Investments

While your money would not be locked up, it keeps it further out of your reach, just like bonds. Every step further away from your bank account the funds get, the less likely you are to surrender to giving away money that is rightfully yours.

It comes with the added advantage of typically high-returns.

#### Trust Fund

Trust funds can be set up with anyone as the beneficiary, and provide legal barriers so long as the beneficiary isn't also the executor. While it can be expensive to do so, you could hire a lawyer who specialises in estate law to set up a trust fund you are the beneficiary of, which has stipulations as to how and when assets can be released.

#### Others

I didn't include this as one of the main three, because it doesn't allow you to specify exactly when funds are released to you, but in many countries (including the US) you have special tax advantaged retirement accounts, where funds are locked away until you retire.

However, it is unfortunate you even need to think about this. Another thing to consider is that if people start pressuring you for money, you should cut them out of your life.

Comment: +1, good answer. Another reason the retirement accounts aren't really the answer to this is that there are limits to the amount of money you can put in them each year.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no need for the money. Donate it. Spend the next few years determining what charities make sense and then when the wills are settled, then make those donations.

You should get advice how how to best do that, there can be some limitations and complications. Sometimes the source of the money/property makes it more complicated. The form of the inheritance can also make a difference.

You could even setup a charitable trust to spread the donations out over year or decade. You could even make it so that you can live off the interest until you die, and then the rest goes to the charity.

Note: just because they have no other children, there is no guarantee that you will receive the money/property. They, at any time, could write a will and cut you out of some, most , or all of the wealth.

Comment: "I have my own career and live comfortably enough that I don't need the money." - This is true today. We don't know his age. Anyone can sustain a disease or injury that will kill that career and income. I'm not confident enough in our medical system to rule out the need for him to consider a multimillion dollar stash a guarantee he'll afford what comes his way. Huge charitable donation are great for those who are billionaires or on their death beds. Still we have no idea of the numbers involved. What is "large" to you?

Comment: +1 for :"remember that there is no guaranted you will inherit". Wills can be changed at any time, and your golks will set their own priorities.. There us no way you can prevent from inheriting what the will gives them short ofa major court battle to decare the giver incompetent or something of that sort... and if you try that you're begging to be written out of the will entirely.